# ImageMagick display WxH+x+y window

Tags: bash, imagemagick, screenshot, tesseract-ocr

In ImageMagick's display, if I press 'c' and start to drag a crop frame, a small box appears at top left showing WxH+x+y for the crop frame.

Is there any way that data can be accessed programmatically in bash, other than taking a screenshot and running tesseract-ocr or the like on the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using X11, the text written in the box is done using graphics commands that are sent over the socket connection to the X11 server. These commands can be inspected by interposing the utility `xscope`. For example,

```
xscope -v1 -i1
```

will start listening for connections to display `:1` (`-i1`) and print to stdout (at verbose level 1) the X11 commands received before sending them on to the real display, presumably `:0`.  So you can then simply run `DISPLAY=:1 display my.jpg` or similar and look out this output, typically:

```
         ............REQUEST: PolyText8
                    drawable: DWB 02e002f3
                          gc: GXC 02e00099
                           x: 11
                           y: 18
                       items:
                       delta: 0
          text item 8 string: " 53x48+310+109"
```

A simple `sed` script can extract this text item for further processing:

```
xscope -v1 -i1 |
sed -n '/text item 8 string: " /{s///;s/"//p}'
```

---

An alternative program doing a similar job is `x11trace`, sometimes known as `xtrace`.

```
x11trace -D:1
```

produces output like

```
000:<:14fa: 32: Request(74): PolyText8 drawable=0x02e002f3 gc=0x02e00099 x=11 y=18 texts={delta=0 s=' 26x38+425+297'};
```

which can be filtered with

```
sed -n "/PolyText8 /{s/.*s='//;s/'.*//p}"
```

Comment: This sounds ideal, but the only source of a package for it I could find is https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=X11%3AXOrg&package=xscope which is available as an rpm, and I believe there is a method for installing rpms on ubuntu systems. I'll check back again later with progress report.

Comment: xtrace it is, as it is in the ubuntu packages, and installs immediately.  I got xscope installed too with 'alien', but still can't use it till I update this library: 'xscope: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by xscope). And contrary to this site's protocol, your answer is excellent, many thanks for it.

Comment: Don't forget to tick the answer, so others know it is solved.

Comment: Never knew that about the tick, always thought the preferred answer was the one that collected the most up-votes. Not sure if xtrace works differently to xscope, but to get what I needed inside my script I used;  >~/xtr.txt; xtrace display $a &>> ~/xtr.txt; e=$(grep -o '[0-9]*x[0-9]*+[0-9]*+[0-9]*' ~/xtr.txt|tail -1) where $a is the current image filename and e becomes the last WxH+x+y reported by xtrace when I press Enter and q on the displayed image. Simpler than my original effort with tesseract, and always exact (not always true with tesseract.